# how to make spring AntPathMatcher match optional parent dirs?

Tags: spring, glob

I wrote an AntPathMatcher pattern: `**/pub/**`

it can match `a/pub/b`

but can't match `/pub/b`

how to make it match both?

Comment: You can add multiple matcher

Comment: it should have worker. try making it `/**/pub/**`